# Select TOP 2 values for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having problem with getting only TOP 2 values for each group (groups are in column).

Example :

```
ID    Group    Value
1        A       30
2        A      150
3        A       40
4        A       70
5        B        0
6        B      100
7        B       90
```

I expect my output to be

```
ID    Group    Value
 1       A       150
 2       A        70
 3       B       100
 4       B        90
```

Simply, for each group I want just 2 rows with the highest Value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most databases support the ANSI standard `row_number()` function.  You would use it as:

```
select group, value
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by group order by value desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

To set the `id` you can use `row_number()` in the outer query:

```
select row_number() over (order by group, value) as id,
       group, value
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by group order by value desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

However, changing the `id` seems suspicious.

Comment: @o_O  Editing an answer for simple oversites/typos... sure.  Editing an answer to impose your personal preferences... I find presumptuous.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I'm sorry, being *presumptuous* wasn't my intention. I've seen people formatting SQL queries the way I did, so I thought to do the same., my bad! Will rollback

Comment: @o_O No worries and no apologies necessary.  Again, just my opinion,'

Comment: @o_O . . . I'm pretty neutral on whether keywords should be capitalized (I generally don't capitalize them; why bother the pinky finger so much?).  I am very particular about indentation.  My indentation style is described in Chapter 1 of "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel".

Answer (score 5):

You can use `CTE` with rank function `ROW_NUMBER()` .

Here is query to get your result.

```
;WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT Group, value,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Group ORDER BY value DESC) AS rn
    FROM test
  )
SELECT Group, value FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY value
```

Comment: Years later and its good. The most straight forward and working answer.